# git suboptimal memory error: how to remove unecessary files from a commit?

Tags: git

I made an error when adding files to a commit:
I made a git add directory_name/, which resulted in added very large files (satellites images). Obviously, those images should not be added to the git repository.

When doing a git push, I'm returned "warning: suboptimal pack - out of memory".
My idea would be to see what files are in the commit, and remove the large images that should not be there:

1. How can I see the list of files in the commit?
2. How can I remove the unwanted files?

Comment: `git diff --name-only HEAD^` and `git rebase -i HEAD^` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is erase the previous commit with

```
git reset HEAD^
```

You can then use git status to see all the tracked / untracked files

```
git status
```

Then you can do the commit all over again, without adding the unwanted file.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! For the record, I had to reset HEADT a couple of time as I did another commit after my mistake...